# Absolute irreducibility for schurs lemma over local field

Tags: representation-theory, local-field, galois-representations

I have a representation $\rho: G \rightarrow GL(V)$ where $G$ is a Galois group of an extension of $p$-adic fields ($p \neq 3$) and $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}_3$.

Now I know that this representation is irreducible when we extend scalars to consider $V$ as a $\mathbb{C}$ vector space so does this mean it is irreducible over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_3}$ as well?

I wish to use Schur's lemma to tell me that the image of some element is scalar but I am not sure if this scalar must live in $\mathbb{Q}_3$ since this field is not algebraically closed.

Comment: I'm assuming you've fixed an embedding $\mathbb Q_3\hookrightarrow\overline{\mathbb Q}_3\hookrightarrow\mathbb C$. If $\rho$ is irreducible over $\mathbb C$, then it's certainly irreducible over any subfield of $\mathbb C$ (i.e. absolutely irreducible $\implies$ reducible).

Comment: I agree that absolutely irreducible would imply irreducible over any subfield but the two topologies are entirely different which is why I am hesitant about using an embedding.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something then - how are you extending scalars to $\mathbb C$ if you want to preserve continuity? In order to extend scalars, don't you need to fix an embedding?

Comment: Hmm I do need to fix an embedding but I guess this is only an embedding of fields and not topological spaces.

Comment: What about the second part then, given the representation is absolutely irreducible (over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_3}$) would this imply the image of an element in the center of $G$ is scalar over $\mathbb{Q}_3$? Schur's lemma certainly says it would be over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_3}$ but I'm not sure about the base field.